# MatLab is displaying uncalculated line

Tags: matlab

I am doing symbolic for function u and v.

I did

[image]

Then Matlab displayed

[image]

This is uncalculated! How can I force MatLab to calculate it?

Comment: how did you assign the matrix?

Comment: @yar  I used symbolic math. I am guessing that has caused some problem.

Comment: @yar I reformulated question because I think I found a deeper cause of the problem.

Comment: try `double(temp_new)`

Comment: It's not "uncalculated"; it's exact.  As @yar indicated, use `double` to generate a finite precision representation of the values.